# GCC C compile error, void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c, gcc

I'm having trouble compiling some C code.
When I compile, I'l get this error:

```
player.c: In function ‘login’:  
player.c:54:17: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

This is the code for the error:

```
static bool login(const char *username, const char *password) {
    sp_error err = sp_session_login(g_sess, username, password, remember_me);
    printf("Signing in...\n");
    if (SP_ERROR_OK != err) {
        printf("Could not signin\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Any way to bypass this kind of error?
Thanks

**Edit:**
All sp_ functions are from libspotify

Comment: Show the declaration of `sp_session_login()`.

Comment: You have bool defined in C? Not good practice.

Comment: If you use `clang`, you might get better error messages, too.

Comment: Maybe you could add some information, such as the precise line that triggers the error, and also the definition of your typedef (or class) `sp_error` and the `sp_session_login` function prototype. Finally, where are `g_sess` and `remember_me` coming from?

Comment: A login function that has no error return, that's weird.  Well, very understandable mistake.

Comment: @James: bool is just fine in C99 if you include <stdbool.h>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where is the error line exactly?

Without further information, I'm guessing it's here:

```
sp_error err = sp_session_login(g_sess, username, password, remember_me);
```

I guess sp_session_login is returning the void.

Try:

```
static bool login(const char *username, const char *password) {
    sp_session_login(g_sess, username, password, remember_me);
    printf("Signing in...\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Confirmed, `sp_session_login` is a `void` function: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/11.1.60/group__session.html

Answer (score 8):

It usually means you assign the return of a void function to something, which is of course an error.

In your case, I guess the `sp_session_login` function is a void one, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that `sp_session_login` is declared as returning `void` and not `sp_error` and there is some alternative way of determining whether it succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like [`sp_session_login`](http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/docs/group__session.html#gac2e84f678eb00f08c2a8e5a9a73a02a2) actually returns anything. In particular, it doesn't return an `sp_error`, so there's no way this could work. You can't really bypass it.

Answer (score -1):

You must declare void functions before use them. Try to put them before the main function or before their calls.
 There's one more action you can do: You can tell the compiler that you will use void functions.

For exemplo, there are two ways to make the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showMsg(msg){
    printf("%s", msg);
}

int main(){
    showMsg("Learn c is easy!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

...and the other way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showMsg(msg); //Here, you told the compiller that you will use the void function showMsg.

int main(){
    showMsg("Learn c is easy!!!");
    return 0;
}

void showMsg(msg){
    printf("%s", msg);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. *All* functions should be declared before use (C99 requires this, and it's good practice in C90). The OP already declared `sp_session_login` by `#include`ing the appropriate header; that's how the compiler knows it's a `void` function. The problem is that the OP attempted to assign the nonexistent result of a `void` function to a variable; your answer doesn't address the actual problem.